# Cant Firebase display data from multiple references in a single RecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

```
      //This is my fragment where i want to print the data. 
 public class GestaoMarcacaoClienteFragment extends Fragment {
    
        private RecyclerView recyclerMarcacaoCliente;
        private Button botaoAddmarcacao;
        private GestaoMarcacoesClienteAdapter gestaoMarcacoesClienteAdapter;
        private List<Marcacao> marcacaoList = new ArrayList<>();
        private List<Servicos> servicosList = new ArrayList<>();
        private FirebaseAuth auth;
        private DatabaseReference marcacoesRef, servicosRef;
    
        // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
        // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
        private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
        private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
    
        // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
        private String mParam1;
        private String mParam2;
    
        public GestaoMarcacaoClienteFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }
    
        /**
         * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
         * this fragment using the provided parameters.
         *
         * @param param1 Parameter 1.
         * @param param2 Parameter 2.
         * @return A new instance of fragment GestaoMarcacaoClienteFragment.
         */
        // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
        public static GestaoMarcacaoClienteFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
            GestaoMarcacaoClienteFragment fragment = new GestaoMarcacaoClienteFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
            args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            if (getArguments() != null) {
                mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
                mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gestao_marcacao_cliente, container, false);
    
            auth = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getAuth();
            botaoAddmarcacao = view.findViewById(R.id.botaoAddMarc);
            recyclerMarcacaoCliente = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerMarcacaoCliente);
    
            marcacoesRef = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getReference();
            servicosRef = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getReference();
    
            //apanhar dados marcacoes
            String emailUser = auth.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
            String emailEnc = Base64Custom.codificarBase64(emailUser);
            String data = DateCustom.dataFormatada(DateCustom.dataAtual());
            marcacoesRef.child("marcacao").orderByChild("idUtilizador").equalTo(emailEnc).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    marcacaoList.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot dados : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        for (DataSnapshot b : dados.getChildren()) {
                            for(DataSnapshot d : b.getChildren()){
                                Marcacao m = d.getValue(Marcacao.class);
                                String id = m.getIdServico();
                                Log.i("Dados", " Dados: " + dados);
                                Log.i("Dados", " Dados: " + m.getData());
                                Log.i("Dados", " Dados: " + m.getHora());
                                Log.i("Dados", " Id: " + id);
                                marcacaoList.add(m);
    
                                servicosRef.child("servicos").orderByKey().equalTo(id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull @NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                        servicosList.clear();
                                        for (DataSnapshot d : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                                            Servicos servicos = d.getValue(Servicos.class);
                                            servicosList.add(servicos);
                                        }
                                    }
    
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull @NotNull DatabaseError error) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                });
    
                            }
                        }
                    }
    
                    gestaoMarcacoesClienteAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull @NotNull DatabaseError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
    
    
            //Definir layout recycle view
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
            recyclerMarcacaoCliente.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            recyclerMarcacaoCliente.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerMarcacaoCliente.addItemDecoration(new SimpleDividerItemDecoration(getContext()));
    
            //definir adapter
            gestaoMarcacoesClienteAdapter = new GestaoMarcacoesClienteAdapter(marcacaoList, servicosList, getContext());
            recyclerMarcacaoCliente.setAdapter(gestaoMarcacoesClienteAdapter);
    
            botaoAddmarcacao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    AddMarcacaoFragment firstFragment = new AddMarcacaoFragment();
                    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.frameGestaoMarcacoesCliente, firstFragment).commit();
                }
            });
    
    
            return view;
        }
    
    
    }
```

This is my database realtime where "idUtilizador" is the same for "usuarios" node and "idServico" is the id from "Servicos"

[image: Marcacoes node]
[image: Servicos node]

Rules on my firebase
[This are my rules from firebae](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0yGo.png)

Then this is my adapter where and what i want to print on it, i want to print "preco" and "nomeServico" from servicos and "data" and "hora" from "marcacoes", but nothing appers on my recycler and nothing appears on my logcat and Run window... Why is this happening??? Somo help?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built into FirebaseUI for showing data from this type of data structure. You will have to create your own adapter, or you can overload `populateView` and load the data from the additional node in there, or you can implement your own `SnapshotParser`. The latter is not well documented, but having a look at this [thread](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/1037) to get started.

Comment: I already read it, so should i change my adapter to a FirebaseRecyclerView Adapter to make it easier? I know that i need to change my BindView Holder, but still i dont know how. I am very new on Android Studio, and i am stuck on this for 5 days... I am very thankfull for your help